# ASP.NET MVC Web API HMAC datetime

Tags: .net, datetime, authentication, asp.net-web-api, hmac

I ASP.NET MVC Web API and I'm planning to use HMAC authentication. I will pass datetime through header, but I don't know how I'll have to deal with timezone issues and maintain as many as possible datetime formats, because I want to make my Web API easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You will have timezone issues to deal with unless you have the timestamp converted to univeral time, which can resolve that issue.